# How to split string by line from url

Tags: scala

I have the following url

> "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/alcohol-consumption/drinks.csv"

where I need to split the string by line and store it in a list and return that list. I currently have the following:

```
val url_alcohol = 
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/alcohol-consumption/drinks.csv"
def get_csv_page(url: String) : List[String] = 
{
    val p: Pattern = Pattern.compile("\\r?\\n")
            val m:Matcher = p.matcher(url)
            if(m.find())
              // add to list 
}
```

It is not complete as I don't know how to do it.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Can you give the example output you want?

Comment: @Tyler it should generate a  list of strings corresponding to each line in the downloaded csv-list.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand.  Can you provide the desired output for that particular url?

Comment: @Tyler it should access the data in the url and store each line in a list of strings. There should be 216 lines in the list

Comment: So you need to do an HTTP request and parse the result?

Comment: @Tyler this is my first program using scala. It is a task that we are given. I am not sure either. But I think yes, as it says "downloaded cvs-list"

Comment: @Tyler I think I need something like this. Right ? `val html = scala.io.Source.fromURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/alcohol-consumption/drinks.csv").mkString`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comments, here is my edited answer:

```
val url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/alcohol-consumption/drinks.csv"

def get_csv_page(url: String): List[String] = {
  val body = scala.io.Source.fromURL(url).mkString
  body.split("\n").toList
}

println(get_csv_page(url))
```

You will probably want to add a little more logic, like maybe taking off the first line (the csv headers)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the file is not local. The file is "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/alcohol-consumption/drinks.csv"

Comment: I swear it is not a hack or something. If you open the link, u will see like a text file where it has a list of countries and the consumption of alcohol. what we need to do is having each line separated and store it in a list

Comment: Are you sure you weren't supposed to download it as part of the exercise?  Doing an HTTP request seems a little advanced for your first exercise.

Comment: It says "Complete the get_csv_page function below. It takes a URL-string as argument and generates a list of strings corresponding to each line in the downloaded csv-list." So actually it asks us to download it

Comment: how can I download it ?!

Comment: Thanks so much. At least now I know from where to start

Comment: one last question. How can I make it print everything ? is just displays few lines then it displays .....

Comment: The displayed part are protocols and codes. Where is the actual text of the file ?

Comment: That sounds like you are having an http error.  Check to make sure the url is correct.  it worked as expected for me.

Comment: I used an online scala interpreter and it works. There must be something wrong with the VM that I am using. Thanks again